# FindAsync to return the most recent 1000 results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asynchronous

I am writing a test to check application logs, which could number in the thousands per minute.  I want to use FindAsync to get the most recent logs. Yet sometimes there are breaks in the service, so using a time value is not accurate:

```
// may return many or none` 
context.FindAsync(x => x.Timestamp >= DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10))
```

What I want to do is something like:

```
context.FindAsync(x => OrderByDescending(x.Timestamp).Take(1000))
```

The problem is that if FindAsync returns too many results, it could be slowing down other services and threads.  Is there a way to use FindAsync to only return the most recent 1000 rows?

Comment: You can try OrderByDesc method.

Comment: context.OrderByDescrding(x=>Timestamp).Take(1000) ?

Comment: This is an async operation, it would have to be an OrderByDescAsync() call for that to work.

Comment: @jmb.mage You'd just do `ToListAsync()` after the `Take(1000)`.

Comment: ToListAsync() will load entire result set into memory. Are you sure want to proceed?

Comment: FindAsync doesn't return IEnumerable or IQueryable. It returns a single result. Find/FindAsync expects primary key(s) as parameters, you can't pass it a lambda expression. The Orderby + Take in the answer is what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds to me like you're overthinking it. In SQL you'd `SELECT TOP 1000` and `ORDER BY Timestamp DESC`. Do the same here:

```
await context.Logs.OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp).Take(1000).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Yes, that is an answer.  But no, the context I am calling does not expose OrderByDescending().

Comment: What do you mean? `FindAsync` comes from `System.Data.Entity`, `OrderByDescending` comes from `System.Linq`. Are you not querying a `DbSet<T>`? If not, then you should have explicitly stated what your `context` is.